# Upgrade pip in Amazon Linux

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, pip

I wanted to deploy my Python app on Amazon Linux AMI 2015.09.1, which has Python2.7 (default) and pip (6.1.1). Then, I upgraded the pip using the command:

```
sudo pip install -U pip
```

However, it seemed broken, and showed the message when I tried to install packages:

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==6.1.1
```

I found out that pip remove the previous files located in `/usr/bin/`, and installed the new one in `/usr/local/bin`. Thus, I tried to specify the location by using the command:

```
sudo pip install -U --install-option="--prefix='/usr/bin'" pip
```

Nevertheless, it still installed the new one in `/usr/local/bin`. In addition to that, pip could not work well with `sudo` although it successfully installed. The error message :

```
sudo: pip2.7: command not found
```

Is there a way to properly manage pip?

Comment: don't use sudo, /usr/local/bin is the right location for pip

Comment: @abolotnov  It always showed error messages without sudo. The message: Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xxxxx.py'

Comment: try `sudo /usr/lib/local/pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: @abolotnov It seems that there is no such directory (/usr/lib/local).

Comment: what `which pip` returns?

Comment: @dm295 which pip: `/usr/bin/pip`, pip -V: `pip 6.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)`

Comment: I manage pip using virtualenv, no more sudo required.

Comment: @zeck That's `/usr/local/lib` (which corresponds to `/usr/local/bin`, and contrasts with `/usr/lib` and `/usr/bin`; there's also `/usr/local/man` and `MANPATH`).

Answer (score 52):

Try:

```
sudo which pip
```

This may reveal something like 'no pip in ($PATH)'.

If that is the case, you can then do:

```
which pip
```

Which will give you a path like `/usr/local/bin/pip`.

Copy + paste the path to pip to the sbin folder by running: `sudo cp /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/sbin/`

This will allow you to run `sudo pip` without any errors.

Answer (score 26):

Struggled with this for a while.  Here's what I've found:

- `ec2_user` finds the `pip` executable, but has a module import error due to `other` having no read/execute permissions on the `pip` folders in the `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` folder.  This is actually okay, since in most cases, `pip` installs fail when not run as `root` anyway.
- `sudo` cannot find `pip`.
- Entering `root` with `sudo su -` allows `pip` to be run without issue.

The reason `sudo pip` stops working after the upgrade, is because the executable (or symbolic link) is removed from `/usr/bin`.  However, what remains is a file called `pip-27`, which contains the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'pip==6.1.1','console_scripts','pip2.7'
__requires__ = 'pip==6.1.1'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('pip==6.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip2.7')()
    )
```

So, that's where our error comes from, as the upgrade clearly doesn't clean this file up.  Not entirely clear on where the name translation from `pip` to `pip-2.7` occurs.

As mentioned in another answer, `pip` now exists in `/usr/local/bin` after the upgrade, which is no longer in the `sudo` secure path.  You can add this path to the `secure_path` variable by running `sudo visudo`.  Another alternative, if you'd prefer to not add that path to your `secure_path` is to make a symbolic link to the new `pip` executable in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: nice explanation @Sector95. Nailed the root cause. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is partly answered by your question. The Amazon AMI doesn't consider `/usr/local/bin` to be part of the root account's PATH. You can fix this by updating the root account's `~/.bashrc` to include it.

Something like this...

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin`

Comment: `/usr/local/bin` was in PATH, but AWS Linux wasn't seeing it. I ran your command and now `pip` works. Not sure what's actually different, but it works now!

Answer (score 8):

After struggling with this for hours and reading comments

`which pip` gave /usr/bin/pip , but the actual pip was located at /usr/local/bin/pip due to pip upgrade and clean up was not complete

So removing the pip in /usr/bin/

> sudo rm /usr/bin/pip

and also adding the new pip to your export path

> vim ~/.bash_profile
>
> PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin

exit terminal, and login back

`which pip` should give /usr/local/bin/pip

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to angelokh

```
sudo `which pip` install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best strategy in this case is to manage `pip` is as part of a virtual environment using `virtualenv` rather than messing with the system-level version.

If you're OK with that, here's the basic idea:

1. Install the version of `virtualenv` packaged with the version of `pip` you are looking to upgrade to to the system-level `pip` (e.g. `virtualenv==15.1.0` comes with `pip==9.0.1`):

   ```
   $ sudo pip install -U virtualenv==15.1.0
   You are using pip version 6.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
   You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
   Collecting virtualenv==15.1.0
     Downloading virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.8MB)
       100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.8MB 135kB/s
   Installing collected packages: virtualenv
     Found existing installation: virtualenv 12.0.7
       Uninstalling virtualenv-12.0.7:
         Successfully uninstalled virtualenv-12.0.7
   Successfully installed virtualenv-15.1.0
   ```

   I used the [`virtualenv` release notes](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/changes/) to find out which version of `pip` corresponds to which version of `virtualenv`.
2. Create the virtual environment:

   ```
   $ virtualenv myenv
   New python executable in /home/ec2-user/myenv/bin/python2.7
   Also creating executable in /home/ec2-user/myenv/bin/python
   Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
   ```
3. Activate the virtual environment and confirm the version and location of the upgraded `pip`:

   ```
   $ source myenv/bin/activate
   (myenv) $ pip -V
   pip 9.0.1 from /home/ec2-user/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
   (myenv) $ which pip
   ~/myenv/bin/pip
   ```

This should allow you to install packages to this `virtualenv` using the `pip` version of your choice, without the need for `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've didn't installed the **pythonXX-pip** package.

I've upgraded mine straight to Python3.4, these commands works for me.

```
sudo su
yum install python34
yum install python34-pip
```